# Does Visual Studio 2013 C/C++ debugger, let you call a function and print the result

Tags: c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm debugging some Windows Socket code, and want to get the current value of WSAGetLastError() from within Visual Studio's 2013 debugger.

For example, I have some code:

```
fprintf(log, "WSAErrno = %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
```

and after that line I want to see the value (the log file isn't flushed so I can't look there).

When I try it with Visual Studio 2013 (typing this in the "Immediate Window") I get

```
WSAGetLastError()
identifier "WSAGetLastError" is undefined
```

I know I could change the code to

```
int wsaErrno = WSAGetLastError();
fprintf(log, "WSAErrno = %d\n", wsaErrno);
```

which is what I've done as a work around but in some cases it is not convenient to change the code, recompile and reproduce the error.

Comment: Always print errors to (the **unbuffered**) `stderr`. That's what it is for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes the debugger will show you recent return values in the Autos window, so look there first.

By convention, the return value from a function call (assuming it was actually called and not inlined) is placed in the EAX register.  You can see the EAX register in the Visual Studio debugger by putting `EAX` on a line in the Watch window.  (You can also use C-style casts to see it interpreted as another type.)

In your case, you have nested function calls.  So you'd have to Step Into (rather than Step Over) this line.  That will step into the WSAGetLastError call, which you probably don't have source for.  Then Step Out of the function.  At this point, it's evaluated the argument but not actually called fprintf yet, so you should be able to see the result in EAX in the Watch window as I described.  (All bets are off for an optimized builds.)

Another useful Watch window trick is to add `$err,hr` which will (usually) show you the latest value of GetLastError (even if your code doesn't call it) and decode it into a human-readable error message.  Learn more about [pseudovariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164891.aspx).